# Prop "to" not working with named path to root on vuetify v-breadcrumbs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

While using v-breadcrumbs from vuetify, i came upon a problem.

I have a named path in vue-router to "/" route, but when I'm passing it to "to" prop in breadcrumb, it becomes disabled. Other named paths are working just fine. Does anybody have an idea what may be causing this behaviour?

The problematic path:

```js
{
     name: 'bar',  
     path: '/',
     component: () => import('@/foo/bar.vue'),
},
```

The breadcrumbs items property value look something like this:

```js
[
    {
       text: 'bar',
       disabled: false,
       to: { name: 'bar' }
    }
]
```

Comment: `exact:true` probably

Comment: That was it, thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use **`exact: true,`**

like:

```
      {
          text: "Breadcrumb name",
          link: true,
          exact: true,
          disabled: false,
          to: {
            name: 'route name', 
            params: {
                paramName: value
            }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Just to clarify a little bit: the `exact: true` flag will cause the [breadcrum-item](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-breadcrumbs-item/) to exactly match the link. Without this, ‘/’ will match every route, so `breadcrum-item` will render the link as disabled, because it "thinks" that the current route is already the '/' path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the exact same issue here.

I've got exact to true and also passing in the to:{} props.

All the other routes are not showing disabled and working just fine.

```
path: '/',
        name: 'stepOne',
        text: "1. Velg Hovedmodell",
        component: () => import("../views/choose/stepOne"),
        meta: {
            /* ---------------------- Velg Hovedmodell ------------------------------------------ */
            requiresAuth: false,
            breadcrumb: [
                { 
                    text: "1. Velg Hovedmodell",
                    name: 'stepOne',
                    disabled: true, 
                    link: true,
                    exact: true,
                    to: { name: 'stepOne', path: '/' }, 
                },
```